# How to pause a Process using waitFor()

Tags: java, process

I am trying to run a Matlab script from the command line, which in turn I call from Java. I call the script multiple times using a loop, and in each iteration I want my Java program to pause until the Matlab script has ended and Matlab is exited.

Using [this example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/process_waitfor.htm) (which works fine) as a template, I have come up with the following code (simplified):
EDIT: added consumption of input stream and error stream

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String cmd = "matlab -r \"my_matlab_cmd(arg1, arg2); exit\"";

try {
    Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;
    while((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
    StringBuilder err = new StringBuilder();
    String e = null;
    while ((e = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
       err.append(e + "\n");
    }
    if (err.length() != 0) {
        throw new IOException(err.toString());
    }
    int pwf = proc.waitFor();
    System.out.println(pwf);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Matlab finished");
```

However, this does not behave as expected. Java does not wait for Matlab to do its thing and close; instead, it goes straight to the final printout command. There are no errors, and the value of `pwf` is 0, as expected.

What am I missing here?

UPDATE: I just found out that if I replace `notepad.exe` with `matlab.exe` in the [toy example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/process_waitfor.htm), it doesn't work anymore - Java terminates even before Matlab is opened.

Comment: Are any exceptions being thrown? Any errors occurring within the process itself? I don't see your handling streams, including the error stream.

Comment: It's often easier to use `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` than `Runtime.exec`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Nope, no errors - the process does what it needs to do (do some calculations in Matlab and save a bunch of files). I am not sure why I should be handling any streams, sorry (I am not a trained programmer; this is research code).

Comment: Check the exit value of the Process. I “might” be possible that matlab is launching a second process and returning immediately. You should also be consuming the input/error streams - so you capture any output from the process

Comment: @MadProgrammer I updated my example. The exit value of the process is 0, as expected, and I see no error or output messages.

Comment: If you run the `matlab ...` directly from commandline does it wait or returns it immediately with a prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab needs also the -wait parameter to not return immediately:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/320908-how-to-start-matlab-from-command-prompt-and-wait-for-the-application-to-return

From what I understand matlab starts the scripts you can pass it as subprocesses, so the main matlab command terminates immediately after starting the subprocesses unless you tell it otherwise

See also: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html
For no splash screen and other options

Comment: Excellent! Adding `-wait` to the Matlab command did the trick; `proc.waitFor()` is no longer needed. Accepted as the answer.